# Efficient ways to remove a nested view in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a single page app. I want to remove a view when switching to another view. In the current view, I have a collection of photos. How can I remove the view and the views of photo collection efficiently without memory leaks?

I did the following:

destroy method:

```
destroy: function(){
  this.undelegateEvents();
  this.stopListening();
  this.$el.empty();
  collection.reset();
}
```

event:

```
this.listenTo(collection, 'reset', this.resetBoard);
```

event handling:

```
resetBoard: function(collection, options){
  var models = options.previousModels;
  _.each(models, function(model){
    model.id = null;
    model.destroy();
  });
}
```

here I empty the $el first ($el wiil be used by other views), so that DOM operation can be done at one time. Next, I reset the collection and destroy those models and related views.

Is this logic correct? Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good article on preventing memory leaks in Backbone Views:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

I don't think you need to explicitly remove the models and collections from memory. You just need to make sure that the view is no longer listening for changes in them.  This a great overview of garbage collection in javascript and backbone specifically:

[What does backbone.js do with models that are not used anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758346/what-does-backbone-js-do-with-models-that-are-not-used-anymore)

In any case, the use of model.destroy() seems a little weird/hacky to me because I think of it as a server operation (deleting the model from the server) and I also wonder if resetBoard will ever execute since you have already called stopListening() when the collection is reset.