# Does removing an Iframe from the DOM free up all the resources it consumed in the Browser?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building a Media Manger library which will open up in a popup modal window.

The Media Manger has about 20-30 plugins which will all have there own set of dependent 3rd party JavaScript libraries.

Right now when the Media Manger is opened and as more an more plugins get loaded into the Media Manger library all loading in there own 3rd party libraries as needed it will consume more and more browser resources and memory.

1)
Is there a way to load and un-load JavaScript libraries as they are needed?

2)
If I was to change the Media Manger library Modal window to load into an Iframe which I could then remove from the DOM when the modal window is closed, would this free up all the 3rd party libraries and plugins it had loaded into that Iframe?

Comment: You can't "unload" a script. Test your iFrame idea while watching a resource monitor to see the effect on memory, swap, etc. You might get different results in different implementations on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to unload specific JavaScript libraries on demand. You should rethink your design if you believe this to be necessary. You can however clear the localStorage, which will clear all cached scripts and styles (if they are stored there), and other html5 resources.

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

2) When you clear an iframe, it does indeed return the resources it used back to the browser, [it is easily testable](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/DfAp9/1/). However [it is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12229850/711416) that you refresh the iframe before removing it, as to help ensure most to all resources are properly returned.

```
$('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();
setTimeout(function(){
    $('iframe').remove();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: never do this with .reload()! It will take up more memory instead of cleaning it!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you attach any event handlers, or any type of reference, to the iframe, it must be dereferenced so that your iframe should be eligible for garbage collection when removed from the dom.

There's a detailed discussion of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758346/what-does-backbone-js-do-with-models-that-are-not-used-anymore).  (Although this question deals with backbone models, the answer discusses JavaScipt garbage collection in general.)